# C++ programming open external exe (Use to handle protocol)

Tags: c++, firefox, sip

I've downloaded a softphone called Express Talk, the one thing this program lacks is the ability to easily click to dial using the sip protocol. So I figured I would try my best to create a simple c++ program that will accept the number clicked on and then pass that information to Express Talk to auto dial the number, i've tried a number of things which typically lead me to a dead end. I'm not too familiar with c++ so hopefully someone here can help me figure out what is wrong, the file is located in C:/Program Files/NCHSoftware/Talk/talk.exe. In order to use the command line to dial a number I can type /talk.exe -dial "5555555555" which will open up the program and dial the number.

This program works and is called dial.exe (located in the same folder as talk.exe):

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <windows.h>

    int main ()
    {
        system("start talk.exe -dial 5555555555");
    }
```

Now the problem: If I direct firefox (12.0) to handle sip links to dial.exe and then try to click a sip link I get the error: "Windows cannot find 'talk.exe'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again"

At this point i'm not even concerned about passing the phone number variable to talk.exe as I just want to make sure that it will open when I click a sip link. I figured that perhaps the reason that it is having difficulties finding talk.exe is because for some reason mozilla may change the directory of the program? I'm not quite sure, so now I'm trying to put the full path of talk.exe in the program so i tried

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <windows.h>

    int main ()
    {
        system("start \"C:\\Program Files\\NCHSoftware\\Talk\\talk.exe -dial 5555555555\"");
    }
```

All this does is open a command prompt window without actually executing the program. Of course this could all be solved if I can somehow just pass the arguments in the applications window on firefox, but that isn't allowed. Can anyone assist me in debugging? I just don't know what to do anymore.

Here is the current code:

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <direct.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <string>


    //Written to implement click-to-dial functionality for soft phones (assuming softphones allow arguments to be passed to dial the phone.)
    int main ()
    {
        _chdir("C:\\Program Files\\NCHSoftware\\Talk\\");
    if (argc > 1 && _strnicmp(argv[1], "sip:", 4))
        { // match "sip:" prefix, case insensitive
     std::string cmd = "start talk.exe -dial " + std::string(argv[1]+4);
     system(cmd.c_str());
    }
    }
```

Comment: Is C:\Program Files\NCHSoftware\Talk folder in your PATH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows Command Processor `start` command has a quirk that makes it difficult to use command lines containing spaces.

If the first argument is enclosed in spaces, it's treated as a caption, not a command.  The solution is to provide a quoted dummy caption:

```
system("start \"caption\" \"C:\\Program Files\\NCHSoftware\\Talk\\talk.exe\" -dial 5555555555");
```

Or, simply change the working directory beforehand:

```
#include <direct.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>

_chdir("C:\\Program Files\\NCHSoftware\\Talk\\");
if (argc > 1 && _strnicmp(argv[1], "sip:", 4)) { // match "sip:" prefix, case insensitive
    std::string cmd = "start talk.exe -dial " + std::string(argv[1]+4);
    system(cmd.c_str());
}
```

Comment: Tried caption but error: cannot find "C:\Program Files\NCHSoftware\Talk\talk.exe -dial 5555555555" and the _chdir causes compile error, not defined in this scope. I haven't tried adding to path yet, as I didn't think that was necessary

Comment: @user: Put quotes around just the program name, not the whole command (as jnylen noted).  Or for `_chdir`, `#include <direct.h>`.

Comment: Ugh I didn't see the include statement, that makes the whole thing work now, thank you!! Well now I just need to grab the variable from the sip link, does anyone know how I can grab the variable being passed from the link? Typical link would be <a href="sip:5555555555">(555) 555-5555</a> Is there anyway to communicate this link to the program? #include <direct.h>
_chdir("C:\\Program Files\\NCHSoftware\\Talk\\");
system("start talk.exe -dial 5555555555");

Comment: I didn't specify how the argument is passed from the command line to the phone, the phone expects the phone number to be passed as "%1" so assuming that is the case, talk.exe -dial "%1" is the argument where "%1" is the phone number from the sip:5555555555.

Comment: Or maybe some documentation that I can read to attempt the get url variable and pass that to the number string

Comment: @user1401863: You didn't see the `#include` because I added it afterwards (you could also have looked at the help page for `_chdir`).  I'll add a small demo of removing the `"sip:"` prefix.

Comment: Thank you so much, i'm still very new to C++, which is why i'm starting with this small program

Comment: Would I declare argc and argv in the main(argc,argv)? Right now error in compiling as they aren't declared, would I need to include libcurl in this code?

Comment: @user1401863: Nothing here requires libcurl.  From your question, I thought that Firefox does all the HTML processing and just passes `"sip:5556667777"` to you as an argument.  For the proper declaration of `main`, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wd819wh(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I got the program working, the very last thing i need to do is install this program on a few other computers, but I get an error when executing "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++" missing I've been reading up on this to see how I can get the error to go away so the program can just work, is there something I specifically have to add to the file? Im using mingw as the compiler.

Comment: The other computers that I will be installing to are win xp's, i don't know why i keep ignoring important information, excuse me.

Comment: @user1401863: I'm not very familiar with mingw gcc.  I mostly use Visual C++ on Windows and gcc on linux.  Sometimes I use gcc with cygwin, but not for standalone apps like you're trying to compile.  I think you need to start a new question for this new problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have your quotes in the wrong place:

```
system("start \"C:\\Program Files\\NCHSoftware\\Talk\\talk.exe\" -dial 5555555555");
```

Comment: This treats -dial as a seperate file, and not an argument for talk.exe >You have your quotes in the wrong place:

>    system("start \"C:\\Program Files\\NCHSoftware\\Talk\\talk.exe\" -dial 5555555555");

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to make use of the Windows APIs.

Have a look at the CreateProcess() example from the MSDN documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682512.aspx